# Making a pdf file easily in asp.net with formatting options for datagrids

Tags: asp.net, pdf-generation

I'm looking for an easy way of printing output to a pdf file for users, especially data grids. Formatting options would be a plus.

Potential scenario -> Users view page with 2 data grids -> Users click print -> Page opens a pdf file that they can save/print

Our budget is tight, so a free solution would be ideal, but I'd like to look into and evaluate any other solutions as well.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177/how-do-i-programmatically-create-a-pdf-in-my-net-application for printing in general, but any custom recommendations for this scenario would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a solution using open source iTextSharp, check this article out:

[Creating PDF documents in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Creating_PDF_documents_in.aspx)

The question was also discussed here on SO:

[How to make pdf ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575584/how-to-make-pdf)

[Crystal Reports in a PDF file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236254/crystal-reports-in-a-pdf-file)  (check out the link in JP's response)

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into iTextSharp more - didn't find the link you provided on it on my search.